# Mailto-link as menu-item in toolbarbutton-menu possible?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I'm using Erik Vold's toolbarbutton API with Mozilla's Addon-SDK and was wondering if there is a way linking a menu-item in order to open a mail programm onclick.
For a widget this is trivial since I can just add a `<a href="mailto:xxxxx"></a>` to the HTML of the corresponding panel.
But what about the toolbarbutton-menu? Is there anything like `type: "email"` for instance which would allow modifying the toolbarbutton API?

EDIT:
What I already tried without success:
giving the menu-item href attribute (including class `text-link`)
adding anchor element as childNode to menu-item

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "footer menu". If you know how to link a toolbarbutton-menu-item then: Yes, I wanna know more ;-}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a link, you can simply "request" that URL yourself:

```js
var {ToolbarButton} = require("toolbarbutton");
var {Request} = require("sdk/request");
ToolbarButton({
  ...
  onCommand: function () {
    try {
      Request({url: "mailto:foo@example.com"}).get();
    }
    catch (e) {
      // Ignore "no data will be returned" exception
    }
  }
});
```

This request will have exactly the same effect as the user clicking the link - no data will be returned but the mail application window will open.

Comment: Oh great! Somehow it slipped my attention it was possible using the request API. Still a bit curious how one would acomplish this in XUL but I will do it exactly the way you proposed :}

Comment: @user1521685: XUL doesn't really have links so you would still have to handle that yourself. The usual approach would be calling [nsIExternalProtocolService.loadURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIExternalProtocolService#loadURI%28%29) directly (it is being called further along the line regardless of what you do). This is exactly [what the `text-link` binding does](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/fe53a0780c6f/toolkit/content/widgets/text.xml#l300).